# How to search character by character in mongodb array text field?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have documents in mongodb are like :

```
[{
  "_id" : 1,
  "name" : "Himanshu",
  "tags" : ["member", "active"]
},{
  "_id" : 2,
  "name" : "Teotia",
  "tags" : ["employer", "withdrawal"]
},{ 
  "_id" : 3,
  "name" : "John",
  "tags" : ["member", "deactive"]
},{
  "_id" : 4,
  "name" : "Haris",
  "tags" : ["employer", "action"]
}]
```

1. What I want to search here is if we have array of filter like `{"tags" : ["member", "act"]}` it will reply back id's `1` and `2` because here `member` is full match and `act` partial match in two documents.
2. if I have filter like `{"tags" : ["mem"] }` then it should reply id's `1` and `3`
3. One more case If I have filter like `{"tags" : ["member", "active"]}` then it should answer only `1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically need **two** concepts here.

1. Convert each input string of the array into an Regular expression anchored to the "start" of the string:
2. Apply the list with the [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) operator to ensure "all" matches:

   ```
   var filter = { "tags": [ "mem", "active" ] };

   // Map with regular expressions
   filter.tags = { "$all": filter.tags.map(t => new RegExpr("^" + t)) };
   // makes filter to { "tags": { "$all": [ /^mem/, /^active/ ] } }

   // search for results
   db.collection.find(filter);
   ```