# Check if at least one word from array can be found in field

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, nosql

I've been searching the web for a possible solution to this but all i can find is looking for values in an array. I have a field in my posts collections called `summary` which contains a paragraph summary of a specific post. I also have an array of words and I would like to check if at least one of those words are present in the summary, but i'm not sure how to go about this. I'm using a package for laravel called jenssegers to make my queries so looking for resources on how to properly do aggregate queries are very limited. I'd like to return every post whose summary contains at least one word from the array being sent. Is this even possible?

this is my query

```
$post = Post::raw(function ($collection) use ($request) {
        return $collection->aggregate(
            [
                [
                    '$elemMatch' => [
                        'summary' => $request->input('interests')
                    ],
                ],
                [
                    '$lookup' => [
                        'as' => 'edits',
                        'from' => 'editorial',
                        'foreignField' => '_id',
                        'localField' => 'edit_id',
                    ],
                ],
            ]
        );
    });
```

`$request->input('interests')` is an array being sent from my front-end which comprises of an array of interes like `['magic','swords','legion']`

Not sure what approach to take to this and any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm not entirely sure which value you want to pick out, but if your array being sent is different for each request you could use a combination of explode() and in_array()

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53148402/how-to-search-character-by-character-in-mongodb-array-text-field/53148471#53148471

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet thanks. Will try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a regular expression in combination with laravel, this would look something like:

```
$searchTerms = ['magic','swords','legion'];
$regex = ".*(".implode("|", $searchTerms).").*"; 
YourModel::where("summary", "regexp", $regex)->get();
```

Here the regex will produce `.*(magic|swords|legion).*`, which will match any one of these with anything on either side

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `$or` and `$regex` operators to search inside string fields:

```js
db.posts.find({ "$or": [
    { "summary": { "$regex": "some" }, $options: 'i' }, 
    { "summary": { "$regex": "words" }, $options: 'i' }, 
    { "summary": { "$regex": "to" }, $options: 'i' }, 
    { "summary": { "$regex": "match" }, $options: 'i' }
]})
```

The `i` option makes it case insensitive.

If you're doing a lot of text searching, you may want to look at [collations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/).

Comment: not quite what i was looking for but upvoted for the attempt :)